# Access violation reading when trying to run pe file from memory

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2019, portable-executable

I took famous example of running pe executable from memory. But when I trying to run it am getting memory access violation on function WriteProcessMemory().

I am using the latest Visual Studio 2019 and I have Windows 10 x64 OS. In preferences in Visual Studio I select Debug and x86 build. The app that I am trying to run(simpleMessageBox.exe) is the same x86 Debug. Here is my full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h> // WinAPI header
#include <TlHelp32.h> // WinAPI Process API

std::vector<uint8_t> getFileContents(const char* filePath)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> rawData;

    std::ifstream stream(filePath, std::ios::in);
    rawData = std::vector<uint8_t>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    return rawData;
}

int RunPortableExecutable(void* Image)
{
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* DOSHeader; // For NT DOS Header symbols
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* NtHeader; // For Nt Header objects & symbols
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* SectionHeader;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
    STARTUPINFOA SI;

    CONTEXT* CTX;

    DWORD* ImageBase; // Base address of the image
    void* pImageBase; // Point to the image base

    int count;
    char CurrentFilePath[1024];

    DOSHeader = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(Image); // Initialize variable
    NtHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((char*)DOSHeader + DOSHeader->e_lfanew);

    GetModuleFileNameA(0, CurrentFilePath, 1024); // Path to current executable
    if (DOSHeader->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) // Check if image is a PE file
    {
        ZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI)); // Null the memory
        ZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI)); // Null the memory

        if (CreateProcessA(CurrentFilePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
        CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI)) // Create a new instance of current
           //process in suspended state, for the new image.
        {
            // Allocate memory for the context.
            CTX = LPCONTEXT(VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(CTX), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
            CTX->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL; // Context is allocated

            if (GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX))) //if context is in thread
            {
                // Read instructions
                ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPCVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&ImageBase), 4, 0);

                pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
                NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, 0x3000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

                // Write the image to the process
                WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pImageBase, Image, NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);

                for (count = 0; count < NtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; count++)
                {
                    SectionHeader = PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew + 248 + (count * 40));

                    WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(DWORD(pImageBase) + SectionHeader->VirtualAddress),
                    LPVOID(DWORD(Image) + SectionHeader->PointerToRawData), SectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, 0);
                }
                WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0);

                // Move address of entry point to the eax register
                CTX->Eax = DWORD(pImageBase) + NtHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
                SetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX)); // Set the context
                ResumeThread(PI.hThread); //´Start the process/call main()

                return 0; // Operation was successful.
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto rawPEData = getFileContents("C:\\Users\\..\\simpleMessageBox.exe");
    auto runError = RunPortableExecutable(&rawPEData[0]);
    return runError;
}
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) a PE file is not a contiguous blob and doesn't map to virtual memory 1-to-1, 2) different sections need different page protection modes, 3) at least imports and fixups must be processed, and 4) you'll probably have better luck with this on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 2) you need to allocate space in the other process (VirtualAllocEx) that you can write into - that target address doesn't magically exist over there.